# Why is the process table limited to 64k processes?

Tags: unix

Why haven't modern unixes expanded the table?  64k seems small to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly for the same reason why a timestamp is still 32 bit: Because there’s too much cruft around that depends on process IDs being limited to 16 bit.

Hmm, wasn’t there a Linux kernel option that allowed you to use larger PIDs…?